# When is rxjs observable subscribe executed synchronously?

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

With below code block,

```js
let ob = of(1,2,3);
ob.subscribe((v)=>{
   console.log(v)
})
console.log("end")
```

the values are emitted synchronously. Is the function within subscribe guaranteed to be executed before print `end`?
 so the output will always be.

```
1
2
3
end
```

Comment: You could see if the output changes if you throw in some delay before printing within the function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if your observable stream is running sync code only, yes it just like running normal function execution synchronously, but if it's async it'll run asynchronously, whereas promise will always run asynchronously

The async version of your code will be something like

```
let ob = of(1,2,3).pipe(mergeMap(num=>timer(0),_=>num);
ob.subscribe((v)=>{
   console.log(v)
})
console.log("end")
```

Answer (score 1):

Not if the observable emits later

```js
const { BehaviorSubject } = rxjs;

let bs$ = new BehaviorSubject(1);

setTimeout(() => { bs$.next(2); }, 500);
setTimeout(() => { bs$.next(3); }, 1000);

bs$.subscribe(v => {
   console.log(v)
});

console.log('end');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.5.3/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The observables are `Stream of Data` not`async functions`. runs synchronously and depends of the logic inside the osbervable it call the next method synchroniusly oner or manytimes (like a of operator) or async like  if you call the next method inside of SetTimeout function.